# Shell script does not work when pushed to device

Tags: android, shell, adb

**What i want**

I want to remove some google Apps with a shell script, started from my windows client using adb.

**What is the problem**

When I use following command in command prompt using adb / shell it works.

```
pm uninstall --user 0 com.google.android.apps.maps
```

But when I put the same command into a shell script, push it to my phone and try to run it - it gives the *app is not installed* error!

Comment: but why does it work, when I try it directly from command prompt?

Comment: I just rewrote the question. So now it is better understandable :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with a little workaround.
I just start the pm uninstall command also from the batch and do not push it to the device.

Like this: (uninstall.bat)

```
adb shell pm uninstall --user 0 com.google.android.gm
adb shell pm uninstall --user 0 com.google.android.apps.maps
adb shell pm uninstall --user 0 com.google.android.youtube
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

The script you created on your Windows system contains MS-DOS/Windows style newlines (i.e. `\r\n`). Android shell uses Linux style newlines (`\n`). So your script gets an extra `\r` character at the end of every line and your 
`pm uninstall --user 0 com.google.android.apps.maps` becomes `pm uninstall --user 0 com.google.android.apps.maps\r`.

Your script tries to uninstall a package named `com.google.android.apps.maps\r` - which does not exist.

To fix the issue you need to remove all those `\r` from your script after pushing it to the phone using `sed -i 's/\r$//' script.sh` command for example.